Angular SSR (Server Side Rendering) not keeping the singleton state of a service
I have a root service, that keeps the jwt token in memory when the user authenticates.
However, whenever I refresh the page and the page is rendered on the server side, that service loses its state.
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  token: string = '...';
}

// Authorization interceptor
export const authorizationInterceptor = (req, next) => {
  const authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService);
  const myReq = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      // this is empty on the SSR if the page is refresh, even it has a state value
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.token}`,
    },
  });
  return next(myReq);
}

The issue that this causes, is that without the state. I cannot make HTTP calls and the guard redirect me to the login page.

I think what you are doing is storing jwt token in memory instead of that use either local storage or angular store with ngrx or cookie which will be there because memory with vanish when you refresh the page

Thanks, @JalpeshVadgama, I see I will have to change strategy. I go with the cookie approach
